# Is it safe to change an Indian 16A to 250 V round pin plug to a UK 3 pin 13 Amp as used in 220-240 V Kenya

Tags: electrical

I brought an Indian clothes drier to Kenya.  Technical Specifications
Motor Rating (Watts)125:  Heater Rating (Kw)1.8:  Power Supply 220V Single Phase, 50 Hz; Voltage Range 220+10%. I want to change the plug to a UK style 3 pin 13 amp plug as used in Kenya (Kenya power is on 220-240 single phase 50 Hz) Using a Watts to amps converter (125 w at 240 amp) it comes out well within 13 amps. Is it therefore safe to just change the plugs (assuming I wire it up properly!!)

Comment: Are you entirely sure the heater rating is 1.8KW?  By contrast, USA dryers have 5.5KW heaters, and America has a fairly weak power system (because of building our network first, while others studied and learned.)  I agree that dryer should draw 8-10 amps tops and is fit for a 13A UK plug (especially since they have fuses!)  P.S. Got any more presidents?

Comment: Cheers Harper - concensus is a green light ... on presidents - we'll find out in August ? Though as a non citizen I won't be voting.

Comment: @harper I don't know what india and kenya are like but the vast majority of driers sold for domestic use in the UK are designed to work with a normal 13A socket. Dedicated drier circuits are practically unheard of in domestic installations in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

So motor is 125W, heater is 1800W, add those together we get 1925W.

Pump, controls etc may add a little but it should still be well within what a 13A plug can supply.

I have no idea what wiring in kenya is like though. It's not unheard of in some countries for power circuits to be rated lower than the sockets on said circuits.

Comment: Thanks Peter - really helpful ... concensus is its dooable - I'll give it a try and watch carefully when I turn it on !